# pyautogui does not work with python3.10, but works well with python3.8 on ubuntu20.04

Tags: python, ubuntu-20.04, pyautogui

On a machine with Ubuntu20.04 (description Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS, Codename: focal) and python3.8.11 I've installed pyautogui, and it works well. But on a machine with Ubuntu22.04 (description Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, Codename: jammy) and python3.10.4 pyautogui does not work, because pyautogui.position() does not show the correct coordinate of the current mouse position. How can I solve this problem? Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would help if you could also add the versions of `pyautogui` that get installed in both cases - you can find those out by running `pip list` for example.

Comment: The version of pyautogui in both cases is 0.9.53. Thanks for your prompt reply!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Just in interactive mode:import pyautogui, pyautogui.position(), and repeat the second command, with the mouse pointing to different places on the screen. The output is not what one would expect.

Answer (score 0):

I am also searching for a solution to this issue and this is what I have found.

1. Try restarting your system after installing pyautogui.
2. Try using just one monitor.

Thanks,
Rahul

Answer (score 0):

Use ubuntu with XORG,It will work

Comment: Do you mean ubuntu and XORG instead of pyautogui?